# How can I sort an ImmutableJS List object on multiple keys?

Tags: javascript, sorting, immutable.js

I have a list of work history objects that have `start` and `end` date fields. I need to sort by `start` and then by `end`. If the dates overlap between work history objects when I use back-to-back `sort()` functions, the order can potentially be off. I need a way to sort an ImmutableJS List by multiple keys where the second sort key is only processed when first key values are equal. I would have assumed that ImmutableJS would have a simpler way to handle this type of sorting. Here is what I came up with, but this feels horrible to me (using momentJS for date comparison):

```
    const sortedWorkHistory = workHistory.sort((b, a) => {
        const aTo = moment(a.get('to') === null ? undefined : a.get('to'));
        const bTo = moment(b.get('to') === null ? undefined : b.get('to'));

        if (aTo.isBefore(bTo)) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (bTo.isBefore(aTo)) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    })
    .sort((b, a) => {
        const aTo = moment(a.get('to') === null ? undefined : a.get('to'));
        const bTo = moment(b.get('to') === null ? undefined : b.get('to'));

        if (aTo === bTo) {
            const aFrom = moment(a.get('from'));
            const bFrom = moment(b.get('from'));

            if (aFrom.isBefore(bFrom)) {
                return -1;
            }

            if (bFrom.isBefore(aFrom)) {
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aTo === bTo` is never going to be equal the way you are defining it. You're comparing references to objects which are always different. You'll need to use moments `.isSame` method. You can verify that by trying this:

```
const a = moment().startOf('day');
const b = moment().startOf('day');
console.log(a === b);  // false
console.log(a.isSame(b));  // true
```

Here is what I'd do:

```
// Helper function to create moments
function parseMoment(date) {
    return moment(date === null ? undefined : date);
}

const sortedWorkHistory = workHistory
    .sort((a, b) => parseMoment(a.get('to')).diff(parseMoment(b.get('to'))))
    .sort((a, b) => {
        if(parseMoment(a.get('to')).isSame(parseMoment(b.get('to')))) {
            return parseMoment(a.get('from')).diff(parseMoment(b.get('from')))
        }
        return 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You could put that into a single compare function like this:

```
const sortedWorkHistory = workHistory.sort((b, a) => {
    const aTo = moment(a.get('to'));
    const bTo = moment(b.get('to'));
    const aFrom = moment(a.get('from'));
    const bFrom = moment(b.get('from'));

    if (aTo.isBefore(bTo)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (bTo.isBefore(aTo)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (aFrom.isBefore(bFrom)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (bFrom.isBefore(aFrom)) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Or maybe even

```
const sortedWorkHistory = workHistory.sort((b, a) => {
    // aTo = ... 

    if (aTo.isSame(bTo)) {
        return aFrom.diff(bFrom);
    }

    return aTo.diff(bTo);
});
```